# Strip array of Postgres Group-By into values themselves without having the "array_agg" as property

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize with Postgres , consider the following query:

```
const getGroupedEmployees = async year => {
  return employees
    .findAll({
      where: { year },
      group: ['employeeType'],
      attributes: [sequelize.fn('array_agg', sequelize.col('employeeId'))],
      raw: true,
      nest: true,
    })
    .catch((err) => {
     ..........
    });
};
```

After executing this I get something like this:

```
{
  '0': { array_agg: [ 'dsadsadsadsa3243243243242' ] },
  '1': { array_agg: [ 'gfdhgfett873hfkjdshkjdsfd' ] }
}
```

How can we remove all the keys (0,1 ...) and `array_agg` keys and keep only the values ?

Comment: Please show what you want by example as well as by description.

Comment: What is your Postgres and Sequelize version?